# How to assign an ID to a JQuery sortable element to allow intelligent manipulation of the list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I've adapted some code that assigns an ID to a new sortable element when it's added to a list.

The IDs are necessary to allow deletion of specific elements and queries of the list to prevent certain elements being added more than twice.

Here is the code for the add and delete functions in Javascript. You can see the add function creates a new list element with an ID called theId. The delete function deletes 'this' which is apparently the whole list.

**The question is what is the syntax to explicitly reference individual elements in the list so I can delete them or perform queries on what elements are present in the list from functions.**

```
$('#add').click(function() {
  var $li = $(' <li class="ui-state-default">
  <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"> </span>Item 3</li>');
  var theId = 1;
  $li.attr("id", theId);
$('#sortable').append($li);
 alert('added id: ' + theId);
});

$("#sortable .delete").click(function() { 
$(this).parent().remove();
  });
```

[JS Fiddle of my code](http://jsfiddle.net/GUpQw/4/)

Comment: Obviously `theId` exists only in the scope of the click handler function. Element IDs exist in the element, so any time you access an element, you can access the ID. I'm not sure what the question is yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDs are a bit of a red herring here (though note that you are creating the same ID for each li when they need to be unique).

However, the problem is that you are saying when the delete button is clicked, find it's parent (in this case the ul #sortable) and remove it. I assume what you want to do is remove the last item from the list. So you can just say:

```
$("#sortable .delete").click(function() { 
    $('#sortable').find('li:last-child').remove();
});
```

Comment: oh and by the way a ul should only contain li elements as children. You should move your two buttons outside of it or place them within li elements.

Comment: Basically there will be another accordion list with a separate Add button for each ID. Hence I want to reference each ID explicitly but perhaps non sequentially.

Comment: also when i move the delete button outside the list it's no longer referencing the delete function correctly. I think it needs to be renamed.

Comment: That is because your selector that binds the click event is saying find an element with class .delete inside the element with id #sortable. So you can change that to $('.delete').click(...)

Answer (score 1):

y not simply search for it

```
$("#sortable .delete").click(function() { 
    $('#theId').remove()
});
```

**EDIT**

```
$("#sortable .delete").click(function() { 
    $('#1').remove()
});
```

Comment: Great thanks, how can I query the list to see if an item ID already exists when using the add function to prevent adding the same ID twice?

Comment: You are setting the ID as 1 every time a click is called. I'm still pretty sure you wont need an ID but I've edited your fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/GUpQw/7/ so you can see how the theId variable should be outside the scope of the click function.